# Default settings for HTML purifier and how to extend it

Tags: config

Is there a default.json file for the html purifier settings in Craft? Now we can configure this I want to extend to include the stripping on non-breaking spaces. However, I don't want to just extend my requirements and not replace the default.

As I understand I would create a new json file in `craft/config/htmlpurifier` and this file would contain the following;

```
{
  "AutoFormat.RemoveEmpty.RemoveNbsp": true,
}
```

Is this all that is required?

Answer (score 2):

Craft won't merge your HTML Purifier config settings with the default ones, but the default ones are [pretty simple](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/master-v2/src/fieldtypes/RichTextFieldType.php#L554-L560), so I'd just include them with yours.

```
{
    "AutoFormat.RemoveEmpty.RemoveNbsp": true,
    "Attr.AllowedFrameTargets": ["_blank"],
    "HTML.AllowedComments": ["pagebreak"]
}
```

Comment: Would love to see this in the documentation somewhere. A search for Purifier doesn't return anyhing.